# Trying to create nested lists from flat list of items with level_id

Tags: php, html

I have an array of items and each item has a depth level associated with it. I am trying to put them into an HTML unordered list but struggling.

The array looks like:

```
$_items = array(
    "0" => array('level'=>1,'name'=>'products','url'=>'/products/something.html'),
    "1" => array('level'=>2,'name'=>'salts','url'=>'/salts/something.html'),
    "2" => array('level'=>3,'name'=>'dogs','url'=>'/dogs/something.html'),
    "3" => array('level'=>3,'name'=>'cats','url'=>'/cats/something.html'),
    "4" => array('level'=>2,'name'=>'ponies','url'=>'/ponies/something.html'),
    "5" => array('level'=>2,'name'=>'wolves','url'=>'/wolves/something.html'),
    "6" => array('level'=>1,'name'=>'bears','url'=>'/bears/something.html'),
    "7" => array('level'=>1,'name'=>'monkey','url'=>'/monkey/something.html'),
);
```

I am trying to get it to look like:

```html
<ul>
  <li>products</li>
  <ul>
    <li>salts</li>
    <ul>
      <li>dogs</li>
      <li>cats</li>
    </ul>
    <li>ponies</li>
    <li>wolves</li>
  </ul>
  <li>bears</li>
  <li>monkey</li>
</ul>
```

Any advice would be appreciated. I am struggling with the code for how to detect when to open or close the tags.

Comment: Before you attempt to make those levels from that array can you explain how that array came to be? It would make sense to create the array with the expected hierarchy in the first place.

Comment: You could loop through the array and keep track of the previous level. If the current level is more, add a `<ul>` before echoing the `<li>`. If it is less, echo a `</ul>`.

Comment: @NigelAngel it is a Magento generated array used for the sitemap. I have not dug around in the associated Model that is generating it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$_items = array(
    "0" => array('level'=>1,'name'=>'products','url'=>'/products/something.html'),
    "1" => array('level'=>2,'name'=>'salts','url'=>'/salts/something.html'),
    "2" => array('level'=>3,'name'=>'dogs','url'=>'/dogs/something.html'),
    "3" => array('level'=>3,'name'=>'cats','url'=>'/cats/something.html'),
    "4" => array('level'=>2,'name'=>'ponies','url'=>'/ponies/something.html'),
    "5" => array('level'=>2,'name'=>'wolves','url'=>'/wolves/something.html'),
    "6" => array('level'=>1,'name'=>'bears','url'=>'/bears/something.html'),
    "7" => array('level'=>1,'name'=>'monkey','url'=>'/monkey/something.html'),
);

$depth = 0;

foreach( $_items as $value ) {
    if ( $value['level'] > $depth )
        echo str_repeat( '<ul>', ( $value['level'] - $depth ) );
    if ( $value['level'] < $depth )
        echo str_repeat( '</ul>', ( $depth - $value['level'] ) );

    $depth = $value['level'];

    echo "<li><a href=\"$value[url]\">$value[name]</a></li>";
}
echo str_repeat( '</ul>', $depth );
```

`$depth` var is for monitoring the current level, [str_repeat()](http://php.net/str_repeat) at the end is to close all levels, for example, if the last level in array is not at root level.

Comment: elegant. I was going down a path of hold current and previous levels and then going to compare them etc.. but your solution is much cleaner. thanks.